# Can't keep clicking on the next page button while parsing the links

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to click on the `search` button to populate results and then parse different links from class `ya_result-item` from its landing page and then keep clicking on the next page button while parsing the links from other pages until there is no more button left to click.

However, my script can parse the links from it's first page only and click on the next page button once but then gets stuck.

[website link](https://www.yogaalliance.org/Directory-Registrants?type=School)

***How can I make my script keep clicking on the next page button while parsing the links?***

This is my try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.yogaalliance.org/Directory?Type=School"

def get_page_content(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.ya_directory-search-button"))).click()
    while True:
        for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id^='ya_result-item'] a[href^='/SchoolPublicProfile']"))):
            print(item.get_attribute("href"))

        try:
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title*='next page']"))).click()
            wait.until(EC.staleness_of(item))
        except Exception:break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    get_page_content(driver,url)
```

Comment: Did you get any exception or the browser froze ? What did you mean by 'then gets stuck' ?

Comment: This is the error (concise) `raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
Other element would receive the click`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I printed out the Exception and it says that the Element is not clickable. Instead of clicking on it, an alternative is to use `send_keys("\n")` to emulate the  link click.

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title*='next page']"))).send_keys("\n")
```

I tried this out and  I am able to navigate to all the pages.

Comment: Awesome @Bitto Bennichan!!!. Could you tell me a bit more about this `.send_keys("\n")` for the sake of clarity. Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU We are just emulating the click using key instead of mouse. It's kind of a hack but very useful sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to scraping data no need for Selenium. You can use `requests` package to get all information in json format much faster.

Code below collect all schools with details as list of maps in `result`:

```
import requests

data = {
    'take': '10',
    'skip': '0',
    'page': '1',
    'pageSize': '10',
    'pageIndex': '0'
}
url = 'https://www.yogaalliance.org/DesktopModules/YAServices/API/SchoolDirectory/SearchSchools'
response = requests.post(url, data=data)

result = response.json()["Result"]
totalCount = response.json()["TotalCount"]
totalCount = int(totalCount / 10)

for i in range(1, totalCount):
    data['skip'] = int(data['skip']) + 10
    data['page'] = i + 1
    data['pageIndex'] = i
    response = requests.post(url, data=data)
    result.extend(response.json()["Result"])

print(result)
```